# I wanna make a placing using json by points in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

i was want to make this

```
var users = {jhon: {name: 'jhon', points: 30}, markus:{name: 'Markus', points: 20}};
```

`// i want it return like this 1. Jhon with number of points: 30`

`// 2. Markus with number of points: 20`

So how i do that?

Comment: I don't see any JSON. And what have you tried?

Comment: The users json...

Comment: I am a beginner so please don't broke my heart :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Object.values()` and iterate through each value using `array#forEach`. Use Template literal to generate the desired string.

```js
var users = {jhon: {name: 'jhon', points: 30}, markus:{name: 'Markus', points: 20}},
    result = Object.values(users).forEach((v,i) => console.log(`${i+1}. ${v.name} with number of points: ${v.points}`));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `for ( - in -)` method on an object to read all the property of `users` object.

see below solution:

```js
var users = {
  jhon: {
    name: 'jhon',
    points: 30
  },
  markus: {
    name: 'Markus',
    points: 20
  }
};

for (user in users) {
  console.log(user + " with number of points: " + users[user]['points']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I would want to make this thanks you very much

Comment: happy to help, please mark it as answer and upvote if it was helpful to you